# Does MySQLdb Cursors not support empty iterator?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, executemany

```
cur.executemany(sql, rows)
```

I have `rows` as empty iterator, it triggers an error.

If I do `cur.executemany(sql, list(rows))` then it works fine.

```
 File "/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 252, in executemany
    r = self._query('\n'.join([query[:p], ',\n'.join(q), query[e:]]))
  File "/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 344, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 308, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
```

The following is the code for `MySQLdb Cursors.py`

```
    def executemany(self, query, args):

        """Execute a multi-row query.

        query -- string, query to execute on server

        args

            Sequence of sequences or mappings, parameters to use with
            query.

        Returns long integer rows affected, if any.

        This method improves performance on multiple-row INSERT and
        REPLACE. Otherwise it is equivalent to looping over args with
        execute().

        """
        del self.messages[:]
        db = self._get_db()
        if not args: return
        if isinstance(query, unicode):
            query = query.encode(db.unicode_literal.charset)
        m = insert_values.search(query)
        if not m:
            r = 0
            for a in args:
                r = r + self.execute(query, a)
            return r
        p = m.start(1)
        e = m.end(1)
        qv = m.group(1)
        try:
            q = [ qv % db.literal(a) for a in args ]
        except TypeError, msg:
            if msg.args[0] in ("not enough arguments for format string",
                               "not all arguments converted"):
                self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, msg.args[0])
            else:
                self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, msg)
        except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt):
            raise
        except:
            exc, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
            del tb
            self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
        r = self._query('\n'.join([query[:p], ',\n'.join(q), query[e:]]))
        if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
        return r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: No, MySQLdb does not support passing an empty iterator argument to `executemany`.

Why not? Because of the line `if not args: return`. This handles the case where you provide no parameters by cutting the server out entirely and returning `None`. The truth value of an empty list, dict, set, or tuple is `False`, but the truth value of an iterator is always `True`.

If you comment out that line in `cursors.py`, then any empty sequence or mapping will throw the same [`ER_PARSE_ERROR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_parse_error) as the empty iterator.

In order for `executemany` to support empty arguments, it has to test whether `args` is empty somehow. If `args` is an iterator, the only way to do this is to call `.next()` and observe whether the result is a `StopIteration` exception; there's no other way to determine whether an arbitrary iterator is empty. This would be impractical because it consumes an item from the iterator and doesn't work for any non-iterator type, and pointless because `executemany` is not intended to be used without parameters in the first place.